# Is playing games where you are the god haram?

Tags: halal-haram, game

I love playing games, and I don't think that they are wasted time. (So I don't think the idea "GAMES" is wasted time).

I sometimes play games where you be the god, I really used to like them but I don't play them anymore as I fear that they're haram.

I don't play any with the idea to be the god, I play them for fun.

Here is a list of example games:

[God of War](http://godofwar.com) (more like an overpowered human than a god)
[Pocket God](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/pocket-god/id301387274?mt=8) (You control a 2d world)
[Godus](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/godus/id815181808?mt=8) (example I found online, never played)
[Topia World Builder](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/topia-world-builder/id534282109?mt=8) (example I found online, never played)

Comment: If I recall correctly, The "Gods" in God of War are mortal and the term "God" is used more as a title. Just a little input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Islam forbid things which harmful or bad. Having fun is not something that Islam forbid. As far as you play them for fun, nothing to worry about it. It may contain some part which can be considered makruh but this does not make games haram.

Some games even result profitable personal developments. [***Even scientist explain it:***](http://udel.edu/~roberta/play/benefits.html)

> Emotional benefits include… enjoyment, fun, love of life relaxation,
>   release of energy, tension reduction self-expression Developmental
>   benefits include…
>
> Cognitive development: creativity abstract thinking imagination
>   problem-solving social cognition, empathy, perspective-taking
>   mastering new concepts...

People even can learn and make personal development [***in games:***](https://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/gpr-14-2-180.pdf)

> In our youth survey, 73.6% of boys and 46.7% of girls included at
>   least one realistic sports game (e.g., skateboarding, dancing,
>   basketball) on their list of five frequently played games. Greater
>   realism may make sports games especially attractive and inspiring. As
>   one boy said in a focus group, “In the games that are real, which are
>   mostly the sports games, you see them do amazing plays. And then if
>   you were to go outside and try them, and keep practicing that, you
>   could get better so you can, sometime later on in life, you could
>   probably, possibly do that.” Dance games seem particularly appealing
>   to girls and meet a powerful combination of needs, including fun,
>   exercise, socializing, competing, and showing off skills (Lieberman,
>   2006).

So it's about your approach to games and how and why you play it. As far as it is for fun and personal development, no harm to play games.

As you stated "I don't play any with the idea to be the God, I play them for fun." So, your approach has no problem. However, somebody plays this games and thinks yourself is God, then it becomes problematic.
First of all you are human, you can not be God. If you are  claiming to be God you need to repent. In Islam there is only one God and God is self sufficient.

> Allah wants to make clear to you [the lawful from the unlawful] and
>   guide you to the [good] practices of those before you and to accept
>   your repentance. And Allah is Knowing and Wise.
>
> Allah wants to accept your repentance, but those who follow [their]
>   passions want you to digress [into] a great deviation.
>
> And Allah wants to lighten for you [your difficulties]; and mankind
>   was created weak.  [**Al-Nisa 4/26-28**](http://quran.com/4/26-28)

Other then this, general approach to things are halal or haram, in Islam if something not forbidden, it's halal.

> O you who have believed, do not prohibit the good things which Allah
>   has made lawful to you and do not transgress. Indeed, Allah does not
>   like transgressors. [**AL-MA'IDAH 5:87**](http://quran.com/5/87)

Comment: Playing games is not a problem, but how do you address the original question (playing God)? Do you have any (**Islamic**) references to support your  answer ?

Comment: I thought "So it's about your approach to games and how and why you play it. As far as it is for fun and personal development, no harm to play games." includes playing God, but i added specif part for it.

Answer (score 0):

I like playing games like greek mythology games and norse games and roman games alike, I was asking is it haram to roleplay as a roman and believe in there gods while I know they aren’t actually gods, like I say “for odins or for zeus we will win” stuff like that but I know they’re not gods but I’m acting like my character is real life?

Answer (score 0):

They're games and they're using gods as a backstory or 'god' as a superlative. In that sense they are not haram.

Personally, I find games a waste of time. When I was a teenager I bought a computer to learn how to program. I played games on them as well. But within the year I'd learnt to hack down to the machine code ... Computers for our generation of teenagers were what crystal radios were for an earlier generation. They were probably better for it too, I might add.

Answer (score -1):

It's not haram if you play it for fun even if it contains blood. If your trying to learn violence you can not play it. If it a hate to Islam depicts people if the sky as evil its haram. Otherwise theirs no harm.